# Why await execute a query of mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

I'm working with mongoose and I had a question about how the `Query` type and `await` work in mongoose.

When I execute `const result = await Model.findOne(query)`, the result is the Model found in database, and that is fine. But if i don't write `await`, the result is `Query` type.

Well this is not a problem, but i don't understand how can mongoose execute the Query with the `await` command and don't execute without it.

I am very curious how this works.

And by the way, sorry for my grammar.

Comment: `await` tells JS to wait for any promises (or promise-like objects) to resolve and returns the resolved value. Without `await`, you're just getting a `Promise` (or promise-like object)

Comment: Yes, i understand how the promises works, but instead of return a promise, mongoose returns a Query Type.

Comment: And `Query` is promise-like ~ https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-then

Comment: Thanks for the resonse! That clears many of my doubts. So await calls 'them()' function of a class/function/object?